# POSIX alternative to multiple variables assignments with read

Tags: bash, sh, posix

In `bash` (works on `v4` at least), the following commands allow to assign multiple variables from a string :

```
IFS=',' read a b <<< "s1,s2"

IFS=',' read a b < <(echo "s1,s2") # an equivalent
```

After one of these commands :

```
$ echo $a
s1
$ echo $b
s2
```

But provided commands are not POSIX-compliant; if run in `sh` (`dash`) :

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

What is a POSIX-compliant alternative to those commands? I tried :

```
IFS=',' echo "s1,s2" | read a b
```

The command succeeds (return code `0`), but `echo $a` and `echo $b` then prints nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` and `b` **are** set, but due to the pipline, the `read` command  runs in a subshell. When the subshell exits, the variables disappear.

You can read from a here-doc

```
IFS=, read a b <<END
s1,s2
END
```

To replace any arbitrary pipeline (or process substitution), you can capture the pipeline's output and put that variable in a heredoc:

```
output=$( seq 10 20 | paste -sd, )
IFS=, read a b <<END
$output
END
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
```

outputs

```
10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm updating the question to explain "`a` and `b` are not set by the command".

Answer (score 3):

In addition to glenn jackman's answer, there is also the option of an explicit named pipe (which is, essentially, what a process substitution replaces):

```
mkfifo p
echo "s1,s2" > p &
IFS=, read a b < p
```